# React : waiting for a promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks, use-state

i got a function that uses axios to get info from my backend as follows:

```
const getDoH = async () => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    let config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + user.accessToken,
      },
      params: {
        username: user.username,
      },
    };

    return await axios.get(API_URL + "get", config);
  };
```

Now i want to save these values into a global variable on initiate so i use the initialstate hook like this:

```
const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState(() => {
    const initialSwitchState = getDoH().then(
      (response) => {
       setInitialValues(response.data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    return initialSwitchState;
  });
```

after that i got a function that takes the values from the db and maps them onto my local variable and this function looks like this:

```
const setStartValues = () => {
    let newValues = initialSwitchState;
        let valueArray = Object.entries(newValues).map((v, index) => {
          v[1] = initialValues.switchValues[index]
          return v
      });
      newValues = Object.fromEntries(valueArray);
      setValues({...newValues});
  }
```

and i want to call this function with a final function that is another initialstate hook like this:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(() => {
    const initialState = setStartValues();}
```

but by the time it gets to the line:

```
v[1] = initialValues.switchValues[index]
```

the initialValues is still a promise. and i cant see where i have gone wrong as i have used async and wait on my initial getDoH() function.
How can i solve this (wait for the promise) before i try to use the results?
kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

First, you need to `await getDoH()` since that's an async function.

Second, `useState()` is a synchronous function, so you need to do the `await getDoH()` inside a `useEffect()` before you set `const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = ...`

Answer (score -1):

Tbh i did it with use effect and it comes with its own set of issues. found the best way to do it was:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(async () => {
    const initialState = await getDoH().then(
      (response) => {
        let newValues = switchState;
        let valueArray = Object.entries(newValues).map((v, index) => {
          v[1] = response.data.switchValues[index]
          return v
      });
      newValues = Object.fromEntries(valueArray);
      setValues({...newValues});
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    return initialState;
  });
```